# Why is this JS leaving out the fourth margin property?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
var parallax = document.querySelectorAll(".slider-parallax"),
    speed = 0.5;

    window.onscroll = function(){
        [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el,i){
        var windowYOffset = "-" + window.pageYOffset,
        elBackgrounPos = (windowYOffset * speed) + "px 0 0 0";
        el.style.margin = elBackgrounPos;
        });
    };
```

Expected behaviour is for the browser to render `margin: -0px 0 0 0` as inline-css. But the last value gets missed off everytime.

If you change the above values to just `px 0`, so it applies to top and bottom, it works.

https://jsfiddle.net/vqdh4k0z/

Ideally, I only want to apply a negative value for margin-top. Is there an easier way of doing that?

Comment: Can write it the same way with 3 values in css also. You can't dictate to dom parse how to handle those values. May also differ across browsers

Comment: So, what would you recommend to change the margin-top property dynamically on this div?

Comment: with 4 way type properties like border, margin etc the only sure way to access all values is by accessing each side property. for anything with color will also get variations cross browser as to type of color value returned. In css hex values will usually return rgb or rgba from dom

Comment: note...my last comment only refers to getting..not setting

Answer (score 3):

Actually, your code works, the reason you don't see 4 values in the inline-css is that writing `margin: 10px 0 0 0` is equivalent to `margin: 10px 0 0`, this is simply the browser optimizing your css.

If you want to only write the margin-top property just do this:

```
window.onscroll = function(){
        [].slice.call(parallax).forEach(function(el,i){
            var windowYOffset = "-" + window.pageYOffset;
            var elBackgrounPos = (windowYOffset * speed) + "px";
            el.style.marginTop = elBackgrounPos;
        });
    };
```

In case you need to know the names of properties, just check the [MDN reference page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Properties_Reference), in JavaScript, the names usually turn into camelCase ones, like `margin-top` to `marginTop`.

Comment: I get a `Uncaught ReferenceError: windowYOffset is not defined`

Comment: Sorry, corrected the code, I copied the wrong one from the fiddle!

Comment: That's supposed to be a semicolon after `window.pageYOffset` right?